# Is there something like remix for deployed contracts

Tags: remix, smart-contract-wallets

Is there any service I can use to monitor my contract, view the public data, call methods like remix has but for deployed contracts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in remix too. You just need to connect to the chain you have deployed your contract to, get the address, and instead of hitting deploy as you usually do, paste the address in the `Address` field and click on it. You will get the deployed contract's instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you verify the smart contract on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/), you can do it there.

If that is sufficient and you don't need a programmable interface, it should be what you are looking for.